# Set file permission

Tags: android, permissions, delete-file

I have an application that shows a list of video files contained on the external storage. Currently the contents on the external storage (like video files) are in read-only mode. They can't be deleted. I want to delete these files; however, I need to change the permission (from read only to read-write).. Is it possible to change the permission of a file programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [setWritable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean%29).

EDIT: Note that this only exists in API versions 9 and above.

Comment: Yes, you are right Sir. But Sir, do you have any idea about what can be done for API versions 7 and 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the "chmod" command using the `Process` object.

Comment: can you please elaborate.. Suppose I have a file variable with the name of MyFile. I want to execute MyFile.delete() but before that I need to set write permissions for MyFile.. Can you give any example?